# Javascript: Taking in User-Input

Tags: javascript, html

I have explicitly defined a Javascript file for my HTML document. In my HTML, I have created a text box where the user can type in their name, then click a button called "submit."

In JS, as soon as they click "submit," I want to store what they have entered as their name in a variable (I'm using eventListener to know when they click "submit"). My question is, how would I be able to do this without using onclick in my HTML doc? Here is my following code at the moment:

```
my_button.addEventListener('click', my_function);

function my_function(){
   alert("Hello world!"); 
}
```

Comment: Much easier with php!

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use `oninput` event and every time the user types in something update the variable in which you want to store the input. The input tag would look like this: `<input type="text" oninput="myFunction()">` and in the function that is declared as the handler you can take the input and store wherever you want.

Comment: Seems clear, but is there any method to do so only in JS? I don't want to manipulate the HTML file whatsoever.

Comment: Of course, `oninput` is just another type of event like `onclick` which is basically what you are using. You can add this listener to your input field like this: `my_input.addEventListener("input", my_function);` , where `my_input`  is the input element.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the code separate. All you'd have to do in the HTML document is to load the javascript file.

Here's a snippet. First the content of the javascript file, and below the simplified HTML document.

```js
let myButton = document.getElementById("theButton");
myButton.addEventListener('click', my_function);

function my_function(){
   alert("Hello world!"); 
}
```

```html
<button id="theButton">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

to add a separate javascript file do this anywhere in your html

```
<script type='text/javascript' src = 'path/filename' > </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

to get the value of the input yoy need to slect it first. then you get the value via  the value property.

see this example:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<input id="my_input" type="text">
<button id="my_btn">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

then you can use the following javascript.

```
var my_button = document.querySelector('#my_btn');

    var my_input = document.querySelector('#my_input');
    var value;


    my_button.addEventListener('click',function () {
      value = my_input.value;
      alert(value);
    })
```

hope this helps!